# Passing asynchronously obtained data to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I currently have an AngularJS `controller` that is basically getting some `JSON` asynchronously through a `$http.get()` call, then linking the obtained data to some scope variable.

A resumed version of the `controller` code:

```
mapsControllers.controller('interactionsController', ['$http', function($http) {
  var ctrlModel = this;

  $http.get("data/interactionsPages.json").
  success(function(data) {
    ctrlModel.sidebar = {};
    ctrlModel.sidebar.pages = data;
  }).
  error(function() {...});
}]);
```

Then, I have a custom `directive` which receives those same scope variables through a `HTML` element.

A resumed version of the `directive` code:

```
mapsDirectives.directive('sidebar', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
      pages : '@'
    },
    controller : function($scope) {            
      $scope.firstPage = 0;

      $scope.lastPage = $scope.pages.length - 1;

      $scope.activePage = 0;

      //...
    },
    link : function(scope) {
      console.log(scope.pages);
    },
    templateURL : 'sidebar.html'
  }
});
```

A resumed version of the `HTML`:

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller='interactionsController as interactionsCtrl'>
    <mm-sidebar pages='{{interactionsCtrl.ctrlModel.sidebar.pages}}'>
    </mm-sidebar>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem is, since the `$http.get()` is asynchronous, the directive is being badly initialised (e.g: `$scope.pages.length - 1` is undefined).

I couldn't find anything that solved this problem for me, although there are some presented solutions that would seem to solve the case. Namely, I tried to watch the variables, only initialising the variables after detected changes, as suggested in many other posts. For testing, I used something like:

```
//... inside the directive's return{ }
link: function() {
  scope.$watch('pages', function(pages){
    if(pages)
      console.log(pages);
  });
}
```

I've tested it, and the $watch function wasn't called more than once (the logged value being `undefined`), which, I assume, means it isn't detecting the change in the variable value. However, I confirmed that the value was being changed.

So, what is the problem here?

Comment: can you try $scope.sidebar instead of ctrlModel.sidebar in controller? Similarly for pages as well..

Comment: Just tried it, nothing changed

Comment: In controller, you need to use  $scope.sidebar = {};$scope.sidebar.pages = data; and your directive should be "mmDirective" consistent with your html. This worked for me. Also change page:'@' to '=', remove {{}} in your html correspondingly (might not needed)

Comment: Yeah! You were right all along! I forgot to change the HTML, so I still had the `ng-controller = '... as  ...' ` and the wrong references. The $watch is now called twice, as it's supposed and the data is there on the second call. However, I went with the other solutions, because they maintained the `this` approach, which I like best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the declaration for the `sidebar` object in the controller and change the scope binding to `=`.

```
mapsDirectives.controller("interactionsController", ["$http", "$timeout",
    function($http, $timeout) {
        var ctrlModel = this;
        ctrlModel.sidebar = {
            pages: []
        };
      /*
      $http.get("data/interactionsPages.json").
          success(function(data) {
          //ctrlModel.sidebar = {};
          ctrlModel.sidebar.pages = data;
       }).
       error(function() {});
      */

      $timeout(function() {
        //ctrlModel.sidebar = {};
        ctrlModel.sidebar.pages = ["one", "two"];
      }, 2000);
    }
]);

mapsDirectives.directive('mmSidebar', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        pages: '='
      },
      controller: function() {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch("pages", function(val) {
          scope.firstPage = 0;
          scope.lastPage = scope.pages.length - 1;
          scope.activePage = 0;
        });
      },
      templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
    };
}]);
```

Then match the directive name and drop the braces.

```
<mm-sidebar pages='interactionsCtrl.sidebar.pages'>
</mm-sidebar>
```

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VP79w4vL5xiifEWqAUGI

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be your html markup.

In your controller you have specified the `ctrlModel` is equal to `this`.

In your html markup you have declared the same `this` to be named `interactionsController`.
So tacking on `ctrlModel` to `interactionsController` is incorrect.

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller='interactionsController as interactionsCtrl'>
    <!-- remove this -->
    <mm-sidebar pages='{{interactionsCtrl.ctrlModel.sidebar.pages}}'>

    <!-- replace with this -->
    <mm-sidebar pages='{{interactionsCtrl.sidebar.pages}}'>

    </mm-sidebar>
  </div>
</body>
```