# Load the JSON file from local by ANgularJS controller and pass it to ANgularJS custom directive scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am stuck in here. I went through few tutorials and Stack overflow questions and answers like here.

- [AngularJS: factory $http.get JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930473/angularjs-factory-http-get-json-file)
- [Fetchin data from local JSON FIle in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753035/fetchin-data-from-local-json-file-in-angularjs)
- [Passing data to a directive asynchronously obtained in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520247/passing-data-to-a-directive-asynchronously-obtained-in-a-controller)

But I can't resolve my problem. Basically what I want to do here is just read the `JSON` file from my local and pass it into my custom `directive scope`.

**my html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl" >
    <bars-chart chart-data="myData"></bars-chart>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('practice.json')
    .then(function(resource){
    $scope.myData = resource.data;               
    });
}); 
//directive 
app.directive('barsChart', function(){
var rectBar = {
    restrict : 'EA',
    replace : true,
    scope : {data:'=chartData'},
    link : function(scope, element, attr){
        var barColor = 'steelblue';

//doing some other stuff

        }
    };
    return rectBar;
});
```

when I `debug` in directive scope I can't get the `scope.data` that's why I get error when I try to do some stuff wit `scope.data`. But its works fine when I hard coded in my `controller` like

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,) {
  $scope.myData = [
                    {"State":"AL","freq":{"low":4786, "mid":1319, "high":249}}
                    ,{"State":"AZ","freq":{"low":4786, "mid":1319, "high":418}}
                    ];
});
```

**note:** I run my `index.html` file into `python server` by creating from command line `python -m http.server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But its works fine when I hard coded in my controller

Your code looks ok except you get `$scope.myData` by async way and your directive doesn't know about.

You can define `watcher` inside directive  that will listen on `data` change

Something like:

```
 var cancelWatch = scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.data;
    },
    function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== undefined ) {
            run();
            cancelWatch();  // in case if you want kill watcher
            }
    });
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jkTwSiAoApcLPaQUr3ac?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Full directive:

```
app.directive('barsChart', function(){
var rectBar = {
    restrict : 'EA',
    replace : true,
    scope : {data:'=chartData'},
    link : function(scope, element, attr){
        var barColor = 'steelblue';

     function run(){
       console.log(scope.data);
     }

     var cancelWatch = scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.data;
    },
    function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== undefined ) {
            run();
            cancelWatch();
            }
    });


        }
    };
    return rectBar;
});
```

Comment: @downvoter please describe what  is wrong with my answer

Comment: thanks @Maxim Shoustin. Will you little bit explain how `cancelWatch()` work? and `$scope.data` set to `newVal`. Here I noticed when I call `cancelWatch()`, `$scope,data` may undefined as you describe your answer `async way` data get.

Comment: @R.A.Munna multiple watchers is expensive item and if you have 2000 watchres - it can slow down your site. Sometimes if you want to update your directive once only - you can kill watcher. `$scope.$watcher` returns cancel callback. So once we got `scope.data` we kill it by calling   `cancelWatch() ` method